# Upload photo blob to s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I have an ionic app and am trying to upload a cropped photo to S3 but for some reason the file does not open correctly. I've tried converting the base64 image to blob but the final step does not seem to work either.

1. I access the file from the `cordova-plugin-camera` plugin which returns a `Base64 encoding of the image data, or the image file URI`.
2. This is then cropped using the `cordova-plugin-crop` plugin which returns a "image path".

This image path is then passed to `showCroppedImage()` below.

```
showCroppedImage(ImagePath) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  var copyPath = ImagePath;
  var splitPath = copyPath.split('/');
  var imageName = splitPath[splitPath.length - 1];
  var filePath = ImagePath.split(imageName)[0];

  this.filePlugin.readAsDataURL(filePath, imageName).then(base64 => {
    this.imageSrc = base64;
    this.canSave = true
    // this.file = base64
    this.file = this.dataURItoBlob(base64) // DOES NOT WORK
    this.isLoading = false;
  }, error => {
    alert('Error in showing image' + error);
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
}



dataURItoBlob() {
  const parts = dataURI.split(';base64,');
  const imageType = parts[0].split(':')[1];

  let byteCharacters = atob(parts[1]); // displays data when printed
  const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length); // displays data when printed
  for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers); // displays data when printed
  const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: imageType});  // displays nothing when printed!
  return blob
}
```

Am I missing something?  This blob is empty when I print it and if I try to upload the `base64` data from `showCroppedImage()` to S3, the file contains all the data, but loads like text, not an image.

My method for uploading to S3 is:

```
uploadfile(event, type) {
  let key = `${ this.key }/${ this.new_doc_name }`;

  console.log("key", key)
  let body = this.file // I set this in `showCroppedImage()`
  let params = {
    Key: key,
    Body: body,
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    BaseEncoding: 'base64'
  };

  // alert(JSON.stringify(params))

  console.log("Uploading photo:", params)

  this.s3.upload(params).then( (data) => {

    let doc : IClientDoc = { name: null, url: null, client_id: null}

    console.log(data)
    alert(JSON.stringify(data))

    doc.name = this.new_doc_name
    doc.url = data['Location']
    doc.client_id = this.client.id

    this.clientDocService.create(doc).subscribe(() => this.dismiss(true))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using a `Buffer`.  I installed [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) through npm and imported it as `import * as Buffer from 'buffer'`.  Then, I updated `uploadFile()` to the following:

```
uploadFile(event, type) {
  let key = `${ this.key }/${ this.new_doc_name }`;

  // I set this.file in `showCroppedImage()`
  let f = this.file.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "")

  const base64Data = Buffer.Buffer.from(f, 'base64');

  const fileType = this.file.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];

  let params = {
    Key: key,
    Body: base64Data,
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: fileType
  };

  this.s3.upload(params).then( (data) => {
    let doc : IClientDoc = { name: null, url: null, client_id: null}
    doc.name = this.new_doc_name
    doc.url = data['Location']
    doc.client_id = this.client_id

    this.clientDocService.create(doc).subscribe(() => this.dismiss(true))
  })
}
```